# REGEXP_EXTRACT unknown function on Tableau 10.0.1

Tags: tableau-api

I'm using REGEXP_EXTRACT function on Tableau trying to extract numbers from a string. My line of code:

```
    INT(REGEXP_EXTRACT([Name], '([0-9]+)'))
```

My colleague can use it and I can't. Getting an unknown function error. We are both using the same version of Tableau, 10.0.1 and mine for some reason is unknown. Do I need to install some drivers or so to get it working? By the way, none of the regex_ functions work on my machine.

Comment: Are you both using the same data source? regexp functions in tableau aren't supported in all data sources

Comment: Yes, both me and my colleague are using Amazon Redshift.

Answer (score 2):

As you are using Amazon Redshift you cannot use the Tableau built in regex-functions. This is because the regex functions are not currently supported in tabelau for redshift. [find out more here](http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/help.htm#functions_functions_additional.html%3FTocPath%3DReference%7CFunctions%252C%2520Operators%252C%2520%2526%2520Data%2520Types%7CFunctions%7C_____10)

In order to get around this you can:
1) Create a tableau data extract from your redshift data source and schedule this to update as required, 
2) access them via the raw sql functions (see [here](http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/functions_functions_passthrough.html))